# I got "Reboot and Select Proper Boot Device" accidentally

Tags: windows-10, boot, troubleshooting

I didn't change anything. Shut down at night, and it stopped to work in the morning. Windows is installed on Intel SSD SC2BW180A4
[image: Boot order]

How can I try to fix it?

I bought Win-8 and then upgraded it to Win-10.

I don't have bootable Windows DVD/USB... Where can I get it?

Thank you!

UPD:

`Bootrec /ScanOS` doesn't find any OS. But SSD drive is detected in BIOS and SMART doesn't show any alerts.

Tried `Bootrec /fixBoot` - returns access declined.

Tried `Bootrec /fixMbr` - returns "OK"

Where could my OS go?

Here is diskpart output. Volumes disappeared... :(
[image: diskpart output]

UDP:
Community members helped me to discover that partition table is broken / lost / corrupted.
I'm using testdisk and trying to recover it. I did something and have no idea what to do next... can you help me please?
[image: Analyze]
[image: Some error]
[image: Quick search result]

Deep search returns this:
[image: Can't recover FAT partition...]

That FAT partition looks this way (when I use "P")
[image]

Comment: Run the following in the order listed: `bootrec /fixmbr`, then `bootrec /rebuildbcd` _(it doesn't matter if it finds an install, but if it does, choose option to add it)_.  Once done, reboot.  Also verify the boot order in the UEFI settings, as the Windows OS SSD should be set as the first boot device, and ensure Secure Boot is enabled.  I'm assuming the SSD is `disk 0`, or is it `disk 1`?

Comment: Tried it, no luck :( disk0 is SSD with Windows ( I hope so at least :)

Comment: Could the function key that selects boot device be stuck?

Comment: I don't think so, I can easily select which device to boot. And stuck key would reveal itself while I worked in console. The most confusing part is disk0 without volumes... Global partition table is empty too... How could it work few days ago? Disk1 is USB drive with Windows distribution.

Comment: @Sergey Please update your question with the output of the following in `diskpart`: `sel dis 0` > `lis par`.  Does your motherboard have Secure Boot in the UEFI settings, and if so is it enabled or disabled?  If you changed it due to my initial comment, what was it set to before?

Comment: Hi @JW0914, thanks for your reply. UEFI secure boot was set to false. I tried to  bootrec /fixmbr, then bootrec /rebuildbcd and then set to secure boot and reboot. No luck. list partition for disk0 (where Windows was) returns "no partitions". Sorry for Windows localization :((((

Comment: The disk's partition table has been erased.  The best tool I've found for recovering the partition table is [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), which supports both Windows and Linux, so it can be installed while running Linux LiveUSB (I always use an Ubuntu install USB and choose to Try Ubuntu without installing, which allows you to then install packages).  If the partition table cannot be recovered, you can also use TestDisk to recover your data onto a _different_ drive

Comment: what could lead to erased partition table? Virus?

Comment: And is it possible to recover it and make  Windows work again? Or it's more from science fiction? I had only windows on that drive... you never know when it crashes...

Comment: Please don't double post questions, as you will be flagged for doing so.  Please delete this one or the [new one](https://superuser.com/q/1510153/529800).  The FAT32 partition is for UEFI installs... you need to restore all 4 partitions test disk found, as they're the 4 partitions required for a UEFI install (WinRE, EFI, MSR, OS... yours looks like it might be the following order: MSR, EFI, OS, WinRE). Once restored, you shouldn't have to, but if it doesn't boot, boot up a Windows install ISO, press SHIFT + F10 to open a terminal, and issue the following: bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /rebuildbcd

Comment: Ah, sorry... I though these two problems are different. This one is related to finding the root cause: deleted partition table. https://superuser.com/q/1510153/529800 - about very specific problem related to partition table recovery.

Comment: it says "Following partition can't be recovered" for FAT-32 partition. What should I do with it?

Comment: Please help  me :)